# ¿Como unir una base de datos mySQL con un formulario html desde un hosting?

Tags: html, mysql, base-de-datos

He contratado el hosting de hostgator para una tienda online, pero en una práctica de administración de redes, teniamos que entrar al cPanel, al administrador de archivos, ir a la carpeta public_html y ahí crear otra carpeta en mi caso le puse "pagina" a la carpeta y ahí dentro cree un index.html con un formulario, el detalle está en que ese formulario envie esos datos a una base de datos.

Código php:

```
<?php

$usuario = "";
$password = "rosario789";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "Maria";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario, "") or die ("Error con el servidor de la base de datos");

$bd = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos) or die ("Error conexion al conectarse a la base de datos");

$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$colonia=$_POST['colonia'];
$codigo=$_POST['codigo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
$concepto=$_POST['concepto'];

$sql="INSERT INTO datos VALUES ('$nombres','$apellidos','$fecha','$direccion','$colonia','$codigo','$telefono','$cantidad','$concepto' )";

$ejecutar=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

if(!$ejecutar){
echo"Hubo un error";

}else{
   echo"Datos guardados correctamente"," <a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";

}

?>
```

El mensaje de error cuando envío los datos es el siguiente:
Error con el servidor de la base de datos

Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"> 
     <head>
        <title>Pagina</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
     </head>
     
     <body>
        <h1>INSTITUTO TECNOLOGICO</h1>
          <h3>26/09/2020</h3>
           <h2>“Favor de llenar los siguientes datos por favor….”</h2>

     <form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Nombres:" maxlength="40" required name="nombre"> 
           <br>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" maxlength="60" name="apellido">
           <br />
           <br>
           <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" maxlength="20" name="fecha">
           <br />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Direccion"  maxlength="40" name="direccion">
           <br>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Colonia"  maxlength="40" name="colonia">
           <br />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Codigo postal"  maxlength="10" name="codigo">
           <br />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Telefono"  maxlength="15" name="tel">
           <br />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Cantidad"  maxlength="10" name="cantidad">
           <br />
           <input type="text" placeholder="Concepto a pagar"  maxlength="50" name="concepto">
           <br />

       <br>
       <input type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
       <br>
       <input type="reset" value="Cancelar"> 
          </form>
     </body>
     
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o investigado?, tu pregunta es muy amplia y basada en opiniones y puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Por ejemplo ¿qué lenguaje del lado del servidor estás usando?, ¿qué motor de bases de datos ucupas?, etc.

Comment: Lo que he intentado es crear la base de datos e ir a phpmyadmin, y ahí aparece la base de datos, ya creé la tabla y el html con su formulario, también tengo un php para hacer la conexión, por supuesto tengo el html y el php en la carpeta que ya mencioné dentro de la carpeta public_html, envio los datos pero me muestra este error:Error con el servidor de la base de datos

Comment: Todos los detalles por ejemplo del código mínimo necesario para entender tu problema, así como el mensaje de error van en tu pregunta, de otro modo poco o nada podemos hacer para ayudarte

Comment: Esa forma de manejar los errores no es muy funcional que digamos y tampoco te dirá que realmente ocurre, por favor [aplica lo que se expone en la doc. oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) y agrega a tu pregunta qye obtuviste

Comment: ¿Notaste que `$usuario` es una cadena vacía?

Answer (score 0):

Si el mensaje de error que estás obteniendo es: "Error con el servidor de la base de datos." En este caso es precisamente por eso (por que no estás haciendo una conexión apropiada a la base de datos), en tu caso en el método `mysqli_connect`  veo que solo estás pasando 3 parámetros el host, el usuario y una contraseña vacía.

Por ende puedes revisar esta línea:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,"") or die ("Error con el servidor de la base de datos");
```

y ver si estás pasando los datos correctos, así como lo tienes estás intentando conectarte sin contraseña. Sin embargo veo que defines la variable `$password` pero no la utilizas en ningún lado, eso podría ser un error intenta con:

```
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$password) or die ("Error con el servidor de la base de datos");
```

y revisa que las variables (servidor, usuario, password) estén conteniendo los datos correctos. Si aún así no se conecta, revisa que tu base de datos que en este caso es MySQL esté trabajando en el puerto **3306**.

Comment: Para eso tiene en su código este método `mysqli_select_db` así que por ahi no va el error

Comment: Pues lo único que se me ocurre es que la base de datos esté trabajando en otro puerto o que literalmente esté mandando el $usuario = ""; vacío o la contraseña vacía como tiene acá: mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario, "")

Comment: Pueden ser opciones, sin embargo considera que si el acceso no requiere contraseña entonces poner "" es válido

Comment: Sí, sin embargo veo que si define la variable contraseña como $password = "rosario789";